# calculate height and width based on text , font , text color in xcode

Tags: macos, height, width

what is the best way to calculate (formated text including text size , text color , text font) proper height and width of text field in a fixed UIView , including word wrap etc

in the following image text is not right align [Check the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEqFz.png)

in the following image text is not properly showing [check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLTZD.png)

i am calculating image height and width with the following code

```
    NSString* text=[textField stringValue];
    NSDictionary *attributes;
    NSTextView* textView =[[NSTextView alloc] init];
    [textView setString:text];

    attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : [NSFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontValue], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:redValueTextColor green:GreenValueTextColor blue:blueValueTextColor alpha:1], NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:redValueTextBackgroundColor green:GreenValueTextBackgroundColor blue:blueValueTextBackgroundColor alpha:1]};
textView.backgroundColor=[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:redValueTextBackgroundColor green:GreenValueTextBackgroundColor blue:blueValueTextBackgroundColor alpha:1];

    NSInteger maxWidth  = 600;
    NSInteger maxHeight = 20000;
    CGSize constraint   = CGSizeMake(maxWidth, maxHeight);
    NSRect newBounds    = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint options:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:attributes];

    textView.frame = NSMakeRect(textView.frame.origin.x, textView.frame.origin.y, newBounds.size.width, newBounds.size.height);
    textView =[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:redValueTextColor green:GreenValueTextColor blue:blueValueTextColor alpha:1];
    [textView setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontValue]];
```

Comment: It would be strange if the color affected the text size. :)

Comment: i dont know but it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Text solution (note, maxWidth allows wrapping if you want it):

```
(CGSize)sizeForText:(NSAttributedString *)string maxWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    CTTypesetterRef typesetter = CTTypesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)string);

    CFIndex offset = 0, length;
    CGFloat y = 0, lineHeight;
    do {
        length = CTTypesetterSuggestLineBreak(typesetter, offset, width);
        CTLineRef line = CTTypesetterCreateLine(typesetter, CFRangeMake(offset, length));

        CGFloat ascent, descent, leading;
        CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, &ascent, &descent, &leading);

        CFRelease(line);

        offset += length;

        ascent = roundf(ascent);
        descent = roundf(descent);
        leading = roundf(leading);

        lineHeight = ascent + descent + leading;
        lineHeight = lineHeight + ((leading > 0) ? 0 : roundf(0.2*lineHeight)); //add 20% space

        y += lineHeight;

    } while (offset < [string length]);

    CFRelease(typesetter);

    return CGSizeMake(width, y);
}
```

Comment: For me, CTTypesetterSuggestLineBreak returns the length of the entire string. Am I missing something?

Comment: The width parameter is the suggestion to CTTypesetterSuggestLineBreak for the maximum width you want the text to be. It then returns a length based on breaking (wrapping) the string so that it will fit the width provided.

Comment: Hi, I solved my issue. I was getting the width from `NSCell cellSize`, instead of the size returned by `titleRectForBounds:`.